# How to write in a single stmt to get expect result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This query:

```
select audit_id, Count(TRAINING_RESULT_ID ) safe
from TBL_T_AUDIT_DETAILS
where TRAINING_RESULT_ID =1 
group by audit_id
order by audit_id
```

gives me these results:

```
audit_id  safe
117       5
118       3
123       5
130       7
131       39
136       38
```

This query:

```
select audit_id, Count(TRAINING_RESULT_ID ) unsafe
from TBL_T_AUDIT_DETAILS
where TRAINING_RESULT_ID =2
group by audit_id
order by audit_id
```

gives me these results:

```
audit_id    unsafe
117           2
118           3
123           2
131           2
136           3
141           3
148           3
151           4
157           4
```

Finally, this query:

```
select audit_id, Count(TRAINING_RESULT_ID ) na
from TBL_T_AUDIT_DETAILS
where TRAINING_RESULT_ID =3
group by audit_id 
order by audit_id
```

Gives me these results:

```
audit_id  na
118      1
147      124
148      8
157      116
218      79
226      47
```

How can I get the following results?

```
audit_id  na  unsafe  safe
117       0    0       2
118       1    3       3
147       124  0       0
148       8    0       0 
157       116  0       0
218       79   0       0
226       47   0       0
141       0    3       0
148       0    3       0
123       0    0       2
131       0    0       2
136       0    0       3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select audit_id, 
 sum(case when TRAINING_RESULT_ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) safe
 sum(case when TRAINING_RESULT_ID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) unsafe
 sum(case when TRAINING_RESULT_ID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) na
from TBL_T_AUDIT_DETAILS
where TRAINING_RESULT_ID in (1, 2, 3)
group by audit_id
order by audit_id
```

Comment: THANKS can yo help me how to caluclate  % of safe

Comment: That would have to be an outer query wrapped around the one in my answer (or in the answer from @AlexanderFedornko, which will work just as well). You can only calculate percentage on the totals, not on the individual rows. Also, you'll have to guard against division by zero because of the `na` status. Something like `SELECT safe / (safe + unsafe) FROM (<my-query-or-alexander's>) WHERE safe+unsafe <> 0`. Or, you could skip `WHERE safe+unsafe <> 0` check if you omit  the `na` status from the inner query by changing the "where" clause to `WHERE TRAINING_RESULT_ID IN (1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Also option with COUNT() function

```
SELECT audit_id, 
       COUNT(case when TRAINING_RESULT_ID = 1 then TRAINING_RESULT_ID end) safe
       COUNT(case when TRAINING_RESULT_ID = 2 then TRAINING_RESULT_ID end) unsafe
       COUNT(case when TRAINING_RESULT_ID = 3 then TRAINING_RESULT_ID end) na
FROM TBL_T_AUDIT_DETAILS
WHERE TRAINING_RESULT_ID IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY audit_id
ORDER BY audit_id
```